# Proper way to return object from autoreleasepool

Tags: swift, realm, nsautoreleasepool

I'm trying to wrap some of our code in `autoreleasepool`. But I stumble with a method where it returns a value. I plan to wrap all the contents in `autoreleasepool` but how could I return the value? I have this code:

```
func get(withId id: String) -> Student? {
    return autoreleasepool { () -> Student? in
        let realm = try! Realm()
        let results = realm.objects(Student.self).filter("id = %s", id)
        return results.first
    }
}
```

Is this proper to return the value? Most examples I found in the internet doesn't return a value from the `autoreleasepool` block.

Comment: You only need to put the `dispatchQueue.async` block into an `autoreleasepool`.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce only for the background `DispatchQueue`? should I include the `DispatchQueue.main.async`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, since Swift 3, you can return a value in the function passed to `autoreleasepool`, and it will be the return value of the whole `autoreleasepool` call, like you have shown.